# python parse JSON AST to additional pandas columns - parsing error from object but not from string

Tags: python, json, pandas, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a python data frame like:
[image]

```
df = pd.read_json('{"unique_cell_key":{"0":"232::03::14062::19965189"},"google_coordinates":{"0":{"location":{"lat":48.186007,"lng":16.3583238},"accuracy":816.0}}}')
```

When trying to parse it into separate columns using:

```
import ast
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
json_normalize([ast.literal_eval(j) for j in df.pop('google_coordinates')])
```

However,

```
json_normalize(ast.literal_eval("{'location': {'lat': 48.2467232, 'lng': 16.4367917}, 'accuracy': 1831.0}"))
```

works just fine. So what is wrong here?

Comment: `read_json` already parsed the string to a dictionary. So, the `literal_eval` call inside your list comprehension is superfluous (and actually the cause of the error).

Comment: Simply doing `json_normalize(df.google_coordinates)` would suffice.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks. This is the answer.